# Jquery disable element on checkbox change

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dw"/>

<select id="oo">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>

$('#dw').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#oo').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#oo').attr('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

I don't see where the error would be.

http://jsfiddle.net/f8jGU/

Comment: just use `$('#dw').on('change', function() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/2gbHQ/5/

**Good Read** http://api.jquery.com/prop/

> The .prop() method gets the property value for only the first element
>   in the matched set. It returns undefined for the value of a property
>   that has not been set, or if the matched set has no elements. To get
>   the value for each element individually, use a looping construct such
>   as jQuery's .each() or .map() method.

**Jquery code**

```
$('#dw').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#oo').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#oo').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dw" />

<select id="oo" disabled="true">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#dw').on('change', function() {

    // If this.checked = true, then select will enabled else disabled
    // instead of attr() use prop()
    $('#oo').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/DzgxN/4/)**

Read more about **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**

You can gain huge from below link:

**[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)**

Answer (score 0):

Your code also works except that you missed to close the `change` function. Please see the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f8jGU/1/

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code didn't work is explained in the jQuery documentation for `.prop()` (https://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without
>   changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value
>   property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and
>   buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The `.prop()` method
>   should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the `.attr()`
>   method. The `.val()` method should be used for getting and setting
>   value.
>
> ```
> 1  $( "input" ).prop( "disabled", false );
> 2  $( "input" ).prop("checked", true );
> 3  $( "input" ).val( "someValue" );
> ```
>
> **Important: the `.removeProp()` method should not be used to set these properties to false. Once a native property is removed, it cannot be
>   added again. See `.removeProp()` for more information.**